# NativeScript: why nativescript android elevation is just working on corners in nativescript?

Tags: angular, user-interface, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, android-elevation

Why android elevation is just working on corners in below image:

[Link of my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owmnA.jpg)

```
<ScrollView orientation="vertical">
    <GridLayout class="viewed" rows="auto"
        columns="auto,auto" >
        <Label horizontalAlignment="center"
            class="viewed-label" text="Viewed Stories" style="android-elevation:25;">
        </Label>
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

//below is css:

```
 .viewed{
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 60px 60px 0px 0px;
      padding-bottom: 80px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      height: 100%;
      android-elevation:15;

  }
```

Comment: Try removing the background color, I guess thats what interfering with elevation.

Comment: i have moved scrollview inside gridview and everything is workng perfectly now